# How to create a nodejs websocket client

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on a project where I need to have multiple node clients connect to a node server via websockets. The clients will send files to the server and the server will immediately distribute that file to all connected clients.

The problem I'm running into is connecting as a *client* in node. The built in `ws` module seems to only support server use. I've also tried the npm `websocket` client which allows me to use node as a client but I seem to only be able to send binary data without any other information like the filename, etc. using the `sendBytes` method.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: did you try [socket.io](http://socket.io/)?

Comment: ``npm install socket.io``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the `delivery` package of `npm`.
It provides bi-directional file tranfer for node.js over socket.io.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/delivery

Comment: This looks like a great solution for the file transferring - although I still don't see a how to implement node as a client in the websocket connection. The docs for `delivery` implement regular js to connect - any suggestions/examples on the client code?

Comment: What do you mean by node here?Are you talking about nodejs or something else?